# Modal not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am working on a personal project with Bootstrap 3, but when I add things like modals/dropdowns, they don't work. I have looked at the code and it is all fine, so I am assuming that it is an issue with the linking of the files.

Header links:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">
<link href="css/carousel.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

Footer links:

```
<link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap-glyphicons.css" rel="stylesheet">

<link rel="stylesheet" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<link rel="stylesheet" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">

<script src="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

I also have the modal which is an exact copy from the Bootstrap website and all of the code for that is correct.

Do i have to delete all of the other local CSS/JS files or something?

The HTML for he site can be found [here](http://pastebin.com/2bktz8t4).

Comment: try after including
<link href="css/bootstrap-responsive.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="css/bootstrap-responsive.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

Comment: Why you are adding bootstrap.min.css two times ?

Comment: Updated http://pastebin.com/3iG7ZvSa

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can see you have not loaded the jQuery-Library. As indicated on Bootstrap's page, you need jQuery for any Javascript-Component of Bootstrap, [see here](http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/#whats-included)

Make sure to load it before the Bootstrap Javascript, like this:

```
<!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery.js"></script>
<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Then you should be all set up.

Comment: I have now added in the jQuery to my footer links as suggested but it is still not working.

Answer (score 0):

You are not included jquery in your code, just include jquery.js before **bootstrap.min.js**

```
 <!-- Core javascript and icons -->
        <link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap-glyphicons.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">

        <!-- Optional theme -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
        <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery.js"></script>
        <!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
        <script src="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I have used that pastebin and replaced it with my original code but now the webpage is not loading the bootstrap css. Please help someone:D

Comment: Actually this contains your code only, so don't want to replace again.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the HTML i could see that it is missing jquery library path. Please include it at the top before any other JS files in your HTML